# Почему увеличение Number.MAX_VALUE на 1 не дает infinity?

Tags: javascript, int, max

По какой причине? Если Number.MAX_VALUE это максимально возможное число.

Comment: Более того, `Number.MAX_VALUE+1===Number.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: @vp_arth более того `Number.MAX_VALUE + 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999 === Number.MAX_VALUE`  - true :)

Comment: `infinity` - это не количественное понятие, а качественное ))

Comment: Но... умножение в два раза даст нам `infinity`... Почему?

Comment: Потому что нужно зацепить мантиссу, чтобы её увеличить. `Number.MAX_VALUE+1e292` - Inf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Давайте взглянем на число с плавающей точкой двойной точности формата [IEEE 754](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) , предшествующее `Number.MAX_VALUE` и на само `Number.MAX_VALUE` в бинарном виде:

```
prev(MAX_VALUE): 0 | 11111111110 | 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110
     MAX_VALUE : 0 | 11111111110 | 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
                 S |     E       |                        M
```

На первый взгляд, разница между ними не велика: отличие всего в одном самом младшем бите. Преобразуем бинарные представления в точные вещественные значения. Формула преобразования выглядит следующим образом:

```
exact_value := (-1)^S * 2^(E-1023) * (1 + M / 2^52)
```

где `S`, `E` и `M` — целочисленные значения, которые мы получим, если будем интерпретировать соответствующие биты в бинарном представлении как целые числа, записанные в двоичной системе счисления.

```
prev(MAX_VALUE) == (-1)^0 * 2^(2046-1023) * (1 + (2^52-2) / 2^52) == 2^1024 - 4 * 2^970
     MAX_VALUE  == (-1)^0 * 2^(2046-1023) * (1 + (2^52-1) / 2^52) == 2^1024 - 2 * 2^970
```

Теперь найдём разницу между этими *подряд идущими* числами с плавающей точкой:

```
MAX_VALUE - prev(MAX_VALUE) === 2^1024 - 2 * 2^970 - [2^1024 - 4 * 2^970] == 2 * 2^970
```

`2 * 2^970` — это огромная величина:

```js
console.log( 2n * 2n ** 970n );
```

Никакое вещественное число из интервала `(prev(MAX_VALUE), MAX_VALUE)` типом `Number` не представимо.
Тогда каков результат вычисления выражения `prev(MAX_VALUE) + 1` или `MAX_VALUE - 100`?

Результат следующих операций над числами с плавающей точкой — *сложение*, *вычитание*, *умножение*, *деление* и *извлечение квадратного корня* — должен быть таким, как если бы вычисления производились по следующему алгоритму:

1. Найти точный вещественный результат операции.
2. Округлить точный результат до ближайшего числа с плавающей точкой. Если точный результат находится ровно посередине между двумя числами с плавающей точкой, то должно быть выбрано то, младший бит которого равен нулю.

Итак, половина разности между `prev(MAX_VALUE)` и `MAX_VALUE` равна `2 * 2^970 / 2 == 2^970`. Следовательно число `prev(MAX_VALUE) + 2^970` есть граница, определяющая в какую сторону будет округлён точный результат.

Если точный вещественный результат арифметической операции принадлежит отрезку `[prev(MAX_VALUE), prev(MAX_VALUE) + 2^970]`, то он будет округлён до `prev(MAX_VALUE)`.
Если результат принадлежит полуинтервалу `(prev(MAX_VALUE) + 2^970, MAX_VALUE]`, то он будет округлён до `MAX_VALUE`.

---

Теперь взглянем на битовый паттерн, кодирующий `Infinity`:

```
0 | 11111111111 | 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Заметим, что он в точности равен битовому паттерну, кодирующему `MAX_VALUE` после прибавления единицы. Если воспользоваться приведённой ранее формулой для преобразования в вещественное значение, то мы получим `2^1024`.

Именно значение лежащее посередине между `MAX_VALUE == 2^1024 - 2 * 2^970` и `2^1024`, и равное `MAX_VALUE + 2^970` является границей при выборе направления округления величин больших, чем `MAX_VALUE`.

Точное значение, принадлежащее полуинтервалу `[MAX_VALUE, MAX_VALUE + 2^970)`, округляется до `MAX_VALUE`.
Значение, равное `MAX_VALUE + 2^970` или большее, округляется до `Infinity`.

---

Точный результат выражения `Number.MAX_VALUE + 1` принадлежит полуинтервалу `[MAX_VALUE, MAX_VALUE + 2^970)`, следовательно округляется до `MAX_VALUE`.